# jQuery list exclusivity function

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to set up a function that listens for IF AND ONLY IF 3 special items are "checked".

So far I have a list with 9 items, and when the 3 "S" (for special) have the clicked class, the background will change blue, and then change back if any one of the 3 are un-clicked.

What I want to know is if there's a way to make it so that the condition is met (blue background) IF AND ONLY IF the three "S" are checked and nothing else is checked.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/stursby/V5Hee/

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yep, add a condition that make sure there are only 3 clicked, then check that they are the ones you want.

```
$('#grid li.clicked').size() == 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V5Hee/2/

**UPDATE**

Using `.length` rather than `.size()` as pointed out as better pracitce:

```
$('#grid li.clicked').length == 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V5Hee/3/

Comment: If you would have read the [documentation on `.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/), you would know that `.length` is preferred over `.size()` (see the referenced documentation page for details).

Comment: You're right, although functionally equivalent `.length` will save you microseconds.

Comment: @nachito: It is not even about saving microseconds (which would be **huge** gain for such a short code), it is more that it is officially preferred way of counting elements in jQuery object _and_ it is common way of counting elements in JavaScript in general.

Comment: @Tadeck That wasn't meant to be inflammatory, I was updating the fiddle then I was going to edit my answer.

Comment: @nachito: I revoked my downvote, since you mentioned better practice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue in your jsFiddle with this HTML:

```
<ul id="grid">
    <li id="a1" class="r">R</li>
    <li id="a2" class="s">S</li>
    <li id="a3" class="r">R</li>
    <li id="a4" class="r">R</li>
    <li id="a5" class="s">S</li>
    <li id="a6" class="s">S</li>
    <li id="a7" class="r">R</li>
    <li id="a8" class="r">R</li>
    <li id="a9" class="r">R</li>
</ul>
```

And, this javascript:

```
$("#grid li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});

$(window).click(function() {
    var color = "#fff";
    if ($("#grid li.s.clicked").length == 3 && $("#grid li.r.clicked").length == 0) {
        color = "blue";
    }
    $('body').css('background', color);
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8W6K2/.

Changes I made:

1. Make all the id values be legal (can't start with a digit)
2. Add a unique class to the special and non-special li tags so it's easy to use jQuery selectors to find them
3. Change your click toggle to use the toggleClass method which does exactly what you want
4. Use a selector and look at it's length to see how many special items have the clicked class.
5. Add the logic to make sure no "r" items are checked

Answer (score 1):

My solution is quite close to jfriend00's solution. However my solution involves `data-` attributes (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttc8Q/3/) for a proof):

HTML:

```
<ul id="grid">
    <li data-content="R">R</li>
    <li data-content="S">S</li>
    <li data-content="R">R</li>
    <li data-content="R">R</li>
    <li data-content="S">S</li>
    <li data-content="S">S</li>
    <li data-content="R">R</li>
    <li data-content="R">R</li>
    <li data-content="R">R</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $grid = jQuery('#grid');
$grid.find('li[data-content]').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    if ($grid.find('li[data-content="S"].clicked').length==3 &&
       $grid.find('li[data-content!="S"].clicked').length==0){
        jQuery('body').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
    }else{
        jQuery('body').css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
    };
});
```

So, basically:

- remember that `length` property tells you about number of elements within array or jQuery object,
- you should store information about which elements are "S" ("special") elements in a way that could be checked within selector (eg. add them special class or `data-` attribute),
- cache the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).click(function() {
  var good = true;
  $('#grid li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html()=='S' && !$(this).hasClass('clicked') ||
        $(this).html()=='R' && $(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      good = false;
    }
  });
  if (good) {
    $('body').css('background', 'blue');
  }
  else {
    $('body').css('background', '#fff');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method using js object. You don't need the window listener. You can just use the listener on the #grid li exclusively.

```
<ul id="grid">
    <li id="1">R</li>
    <li id="2" class="s_type">S</li>
    <li id="3">R</li>
    <li id="4">R</li>
    <li id="5" class="s_type">S</li>
    <li id="6" class="s_type">S</li>
    <li id="7">R</li>
    <li id="8">R</li>
    <li id="9">R</li>
</ul>

$("li").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(".clicked")) {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }

    clicks.checkClicks();
});

var clicks = {
    checked: 0,
    total: 0,
    checkClicks: function(){
        clicks.checked = 0;
        clicks.total = 0;
        $('#grid li').each(function(){
             if($(this).hasClass('clicked') && $(this).hasClass('s_type'))
             {
                 clicks.checked += 1;
                 clicks.total += 1;
             }
             else if($(this).hasClass('clicked'))
             {
                clicks.total += 1;
             }
        });

        if(clicks.checked == 3 && clicks.total == 3)
        {
            $('body').css('background', 'blue');
        }
        else
        {
            $('body').css('background', '#fff');
        }
    }
};
```